# Failed to connect to queue manager 'DevQueue01' with connection mode 'Client' and host name

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, channel

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'DevQueue01' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'myhost(51401)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2537' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

```
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:696)
at com.bnsf.me.echs.inspection.consumer.jms.InspectionSender.send(InspectionSender.java:20)
at com.bnsf.me.echs.inspection.consumer.jms.InspectionSenderTest.testReceive(InspectionSenderTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
```

Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'DevQueue01' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'myhost(51401)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:413)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7814)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6024)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6049)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2537' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2537;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'myhost(51401)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2537;AMQ9558: The remote channel 'ME.JAVA.CLIENT' on host '' is not currently available. [3=ME.JAVA.CLIENT]],3=myhost(51401),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:346)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2537;AMQ9558: The remote channel 'ME.JAVA.CLIENT' on host '' is not currently available. [3=ME.JAVA.CLIENT]

Comment: You really shouldn't just dump errors in a stackoverflow question with no explication.   I would suggest you find out what the queue manager error logs show.   You could have hit maxinst, or max channels, the channel could have been put in a stopped status, could be other reasons.

Comment: sorry about that, to look into queue manager logs - do i need to install IBM MQ client?

Comment: No you need to log into the queue manager server and review the logs,  if you do not have access then you would need to ask someone who does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client side of your connection has reported the following error:-

```
JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED')
reason '2537' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

This could be for one of the following reasons:-

- The channel is currently in stopped state.
- The channel has been stopped by a channel exit.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for this channel from this client.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for this channel.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for all channels

as described in the [explanation of 2537 (MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045370_.htm) in IBM Knowledge Center.

As it also says in that explanation, you should examine the queue manager and client error logs for messages explaining the cause of the problem.

If you don't understand what the issue is when you read the `AMQERR01.LOG` files on both client and queue manager machines, please update your question with the relevant error message and we can give further help.

Comment: My spring boot application is running which connected to same queue. I am trying to run JUnit tests to connect to same queue. Once I brought down my spring boot application, it got connected with no issues

Comment: That sounds like maybe your spring boot application used up all the connections on this channel. However, we'll never know unless you look in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG to tell us.